# Switch characters in a string using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

How would you switch characters in a string using `sed`?
Say we had a number `12345678` and I wanted to switch the 2nd and 4th digit with each other (i.e. number = `14325678`).

Comment: `sed` modifies lines, not strings.  Where on the line is this string that you want to modify? Is the number the only thing on each line?

Answer (score 2):

Group parts of the expression with parenthesis and later recall these groups in different order with `\n` where `n` is a group index. For example

```
$ echo 12345678 | sed -E 's/(.)(.)(.)(.)/\1\4\3\2/'
14325678
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it multiple ways :

```
 echo 12345678 |
 sed -e '
    s/./&\n/4
    s/./\n&/2
    s/\n\(.\)\(.*\)\(.\)\n/\3\2\1/
 '
 14325678

 perl -lne 'print+(unpack "AAAAA*")[0,3,2,1,4]' 

 perl -F -lane '@F[1,3] = @F[3,1];print @F'

 awk -F "" '{t=$2;$2=$4;$4=t}1' OFS=
```

With awk, split on empty string so each character becomes a field, which are then shuffled and by way of Ofs var they get taken to stdout.

With Perl, we unpack the string using an ascii template, then rearrange the order  and finally print to stdout. The default Ofs is null.

With sed, first we mark the chars needed to be flipped. Then in the last step we exchange them with the help of markers. This method scales with any two char positions you may want to exchange.

HTH.